# Combine results of 2 Queries

Tags: python, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have a python script that queries DBpedia using 2 SPARQL queries, and, for each of the queries, puts the result in a list. Then I make a set of this list to remove duplicates, and I have the results I need. This seems like an inefficient way of doing it, if there is a possibility of combining the queries to speed up this process.

Can someone who is experienced at <strike>SQL</strike> SPARQL help me combine these queries to speed up my python script?

For context: I want the label names of both the property and value of all properties for the DBpedia page of the queryword I give to this function (Query 1) AND the ones that have a numerical/textual value and not a label as value (Query 2).

```
def querydbpedia(queryword):
mylist = list()
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
  prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

  SELECT DISTINCT ?pLabel ?oLabel ?o WHERE {
     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/""" + queryword + """> ?p ?o.
     ?p rdfs:label ?pLabel .
     ?o rdfs:label ?oLabel .
     FILTER(LANG(?pLabel) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?pLabel), "en"))
     FILTER(LANG(?oLabel) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?oLabel), "en"))
  }
""")

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
  mystr = (result["pLabel"]["value"] + " - " + result["oLabel"]["value"]).lower()
  mylist.append(mystr)

sparql.setQuery("""
  prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

  SELECT DISTINCT ?pLabel ?oLabel ?o WHERE {
     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/""" + queryword + """> ?p ?o.
     ?p rdfs:label ?pLabel .
     OPTIONAL {?o rdfs:label ?oLabel} .
     FILTER(LANG(?pLabel) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?pLabel), "en"))
     FILTER(LANG(?o) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "en"))
  }
""")

sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
  mystr = (result["pLabel"]["value"] + " - " + result["o"]["value"]).lower()
  if not ("abstract" in mystr):
     mylist.append(mystr)

mylist = list(set(mylist))
return mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use SPARQL `UNION`.

Or you could use SPARQL 1.1 `VALUES`, to apply the same query to multiple resources. For example --

```
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
  SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?pLabel ?oLabel ?o WHERE {
     ?s ?p ?o.
     VALUES ?s {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Leipzig> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dresden>}
     ?p rdfs:label ?pLabel .
     ?o rdfs:label ?oLabel .
     FILTER(LANG(?pLabel) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?pLabel), "en"))
     FILTER(LANG(?oLabel) = "" || LANGMATCHES(LANG(?oLabel), "en"))
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure UNION is what I'm looking for, but I've tried to do this on my own but I can't seem to get it right. If I do a UNION of these queries I can't seem to get the same results printed as with the original 2 queries. How should I perform UNION on these queries?

Comment: Why can't you use VALUES instead? This is much more convenient. Does it not work?

Comment: And can you show the UNION query you tried? What doesn't work with it? Note, you have to keep the variable of the subject in that case, otherwise you can't distinguish between both resources.